# With Node.js, Express when the end of a route is hit does all asynchronous code that has not yet completed stop?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await

**Environment:** Node.js, Express

**Question:** When the end of a route is hit does all asynchronous code that has not yet completed stop?  I have been experimenting for several hours and this seems to be true but is there a definitive answer?

**Example:** In the simplified example below when the `/` route is hit `getInfoAndSaveIt` is called.  This function has a fetch call that will be slow followed by a database save that will also be slow.  In the  route the program will certainly reach the line `res.render('homepage');` before the function has completed.  In this case does `homepage` render and all async code in the function that has not yet completed stop?  Or alternately does the async code continue in the background even though the end of the route has been hit?

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    
    getInfoAndSaveIt();
        
    res.render('homepage');
});

function getInfoAndSaveIt() {

    let randomData = fetch('https://www.example.com/data.txt');

    User.updateOne({ data: randomData }, { id: 'abc123' });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With Node.js, Express when the end of a route is hit does all asynchronous code that has not yet completed stop?

No.  Asynchronous code has a mind of its own and has no direct connection to a particular route.  For example, imagine you were using some asynchronous code to do some logging.  You send the response and then you call some asynchronous code to log some data.  That logging will continue on just fine.  It has no direct connection to the route.  It's just Javascript running in the interpreter.

As for your example:

> In this case does homepage render and all async code in the function that has not yet completed stop?

Yes, the homepage will render.  Your async code will finish on its own.

> Or alternately does the async code continue in the background even though the end of the route has been hit?

Yes, the async code continues on its own.

Try this simple example:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("timer fired");
    }, 2000);
    res.render('homepage');
    console.log("done rendering page");
});
```

When you hit this route, you will see this in the server logs:

```
done rendering page
timer fired
```

As evidence that an asynchronous operation continues after the route is done.

Keep in mind that processing a route in node.js is just another asynchronous operation.  It's not some magic process thing or thread thing.  It's just an asynchronous operation triggered by the incoming http request.  So, there's no magic properties that would go find all asynchronous operations started by this and kill them somehow.  That's not how node.js works.  It's the opposite.  Once you start them, they have a mind of their own and will complete regardless of what else is doing on in the process unless the process crashes or you specifically call `process.exit()`.